# Is there a gameplay advantage to any of the dyes?

Tags: diablo-iii

The dyes in Diablo have interesting cosmetic effects.  Do they have any sort of gameplay advantage?  Or are they purely decorative?

Comment: Might attract the opposite sex with just the right mix of dyes...

Comment: It's a helpful way of keeping your gear sets separate too. I know if I'm red, I'm wearing MF gear, while if I'm purple I'm in my regular gear

Comment: Camouflage!  If they can't see you, they can't hit you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vanishing dye + PvP? Maybe?

Otherwise, no. Dyes change the color of your armor but that is the limits of their power. For the aesthetically inclined it helps them stay color coordinated but they provide no practical benefit other than being one further outlet for achievements.

Achievements related to dyes:

- [Born to Dye](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/born-to-dye) - Dye an item.
- [Color Coordinated](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/color-coordinated) - Equip your head, shoulders, torso, legs, feet, and hands slots with items dyed the same color.
- [Made It Work](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/made-it-work) - Equip your head, shoulders, torso, legs, feet, and hands slots with items dyed in all different colors.
- [Rainbow Connection](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/rainbow-connection) - Use one of all(?) the different dyes in the game.
- [Pink'd](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/pinkd) - Defeat all the bosses with your equipment dyed entirely with Lovely Dye.

Comment: Really?  Which achievements?

Comment: @Axiom: Under General > Exploration there are several, such as Born to Dye and Color Coordinated.

Comment: You should put that in the answer: it makes it more complete (hint ;-).

Comment: @Axiom: Updated now that I have the game infront of me again.

Comment: There's also the one where you must beat a bunch of the main bosses while wearing all armour dyed with the Lovely Dye.

Answer (score 7):

Nope. Purely decorative, aside from a few achievements for using specific dyes.